# IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Yes, I have seen previous questions on similar topics, but they don't seem to help me. If there is a duplicate, please point me to the question, thanks

I have two problems here, the first one is the title problem:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Starts up method1 & method2 in a try-catch
    try{
        method1();
        method2();
        new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch.await();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch
        // block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//This Toast should only run after notify() is called
    Toast.makeText(firstClass.this, "This is toasty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


//Start of method 1, which is currently useless
public void method1() throws InterruptedException{
//Creates new thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                synchronized(SecondClass.this){
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    thread.start();
}

public void method2(){
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

//Sets a button, when the button is clicked, then the code is continued
                final Button bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIsoAbunSave);
                bNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0){
                        synchronized(SecondClass.this){
                        CountDownLatch.countDown();
                       }
                    }
                });
            }


    });
    thread2.start();
}
```

From what I understand, please correct me if its false, what wait() does is it halts all running code until an event, such as a click of a button causes notify() to be called.

The second problem is even before I click the button, the Toast shows up. I assumed when I called wait(), all code would *wait* until I clicked the button, where notify() would be called and the code would be continued. But what happens instead is that the Toast is seemingly ignoring the wait() and running anyways.

If there are any questions, please ask away, thanks.

EDIT: The logcat message shows that the crash happens at:

```
synchronized(SecondClass.this){notify();}
```

Comment: "The second problem is even before I click the button, the Toast shows up. I assumed when I called wait(), all code would wait until I clicked the button, where notify() would be called and the code would be continued. But what happens instead is that the Toast is seemingly ignoring the wait() and running anyways." this is because you have 3 threads in the code, one UI thread that continue the execution and 2 different threads you created, UI thread jumps from creation of threads and continue so it faces your toast !!!

Comment: "what wait() does is it halts all running code"  Not sure what you mean by _all_ running code.  What `foo.wait()` does is, it releases the monitor for foo, it waits to be notified, it re-acquires the monitor for foo, and then it returns.  It does not "halt" any other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
synchronized(this){
//Sets a button, when the button is clicked, then the code is continued
            final Button bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIsoAbunSave);
            bNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                    notify();
                }
            });
}
```

You lock the invocation of `findViewById` and the `setOnClickListener` but not the onClick method, so when is invoked `notify` is outside any syncronized block.

You should move the lock inside the `onClick` method which is the code-block to block

```
//Sets a button, when the button is clicked, then the code is continued
            final Button bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIsoAbunSave);
            bNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                    synchronized(TopClass.this){ notify(); }
                }
            });
```

(*remember `this` is different in an inner-class*)

Anyway the use of `wait/notify` is not recommended, consider using one of the other multithread classes and collections in the JDK.

---

```
synchronized(this){
   //These statements *should* make the code wait until I click the button
   wait();
}
```

Here you syncronizate the `Runnable` not the main class.

Comment: I've changed up the code, but the error still occurs. I've just changed the "this" into "SecondClass.this" (Which is the class the code is in), but the error message is still there.

Comment: It's the Exception, anyway it would be because when thread2 starts, thread1 is not started yet

Comment: So would a thread.sleep(500) fix that? EDIT: Woops, this doesn't make sense

Comment: No, because you are not working with a single-threaded program. It could happen that, even after 500 milliseconds, Android has not started the thread yet due because it can't right now or something similar.

Comment: Anyway to fix that or is it just how android is?

Comment: It's how multithread works everywhere. You could use a CountDownLatch. new CountDownLatch(1). then before the toast, CountDownLatch.await(); and in thread2 CountDownLatch.countdown();

Comment: @Marco Acierno : "You lock the invocation of findViewById and the setOnClickListener but not the onClick method, so when is invoked notify is outside any syncronized block." if he locked the invocation of findViewById so the click listener did not assign to button, can you explain it a bit further!!

Comment: @mmlooloo With "locked the invocation of ..." i mean: If another threads access the same code block it should wait that a previous thread complete the block. The onClick is inside another class and is not executed when .setOnClickListener is invoked so the thread already released the lock when onClick is invoked.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I am not sure how to use CountDownLatch, I tried to use it, but a few errors popped up: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method await() from the type CountDownLatch. Could you check the edited code and see if it is the correct way to use it?